# Mongoengine query to return matching elements from an array of the same document in a collection

Tags: django, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

What will be the mongoengine query to return only locations names that starts with "B" from the below document of a collection?

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5388ae8df30090186310ed77"), 
    "city" : "Pune", 
    "locations" : [ 
        "Kalyani Nagar", 
        "Vishrantwadi", 
        "Camp", 
        "Bhawani Peth", 
        "Kasarwadi", 
        "Deccan Gymkhana",
        "Dhankawadi", 
        "Wanowrie", 
        "Sinhagad Road-Vadgaon Budruk", 
        "Kothrud", 
        "Pune Cantonment", 
        "Bibvewadi", 
        "Shivaji Nagar", 
        "Pimple Nilakh-Pimpri Chinchwad",
        "Thergaon", 
        "Dapodi", 
        "Wakad", 
        "Katraj", 
        "Pashan Gaon"
    ]
}
```

Collection.objects(locations__istartswith = "B",city__iexact = "Pune").distinct("locations")

is not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically need is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) methods from MongoDB in order to do this as there are "multiple" matches for your condition and this cannot be solved by simple query projection. The essential statement goes like this, considering multiple documents that could match the condition:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match only the documents that satisfy the condition
    { "$match": {
        "city": "Pune",            
        "locations": { "$regex": "^B" }
    }},

    // Unwind the array as individual documents
    { "$unwind": "$locations" },

    // Match to "filter" the array elements
    { "$match": {
        "locations": { "$regex": "^B" }
    }},

    // Group back to documents if required
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "city": { "$first": "$city" },
        "locations": { "$push": "$locations" }
    }}
```

So that [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) match for the values of "locations" starting with "B" does the filtering work that is required. First by matching only the documents in the collection that would meet the condition, then after the [**`$uwnind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) of the array in those matching documents it it used again to "filter" the actual array entries.

Optionally then you put everything back as a document with only the matching array elements in the response using [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). So with your document the result will be:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5388ae8df30090186310ed77"), 
    "city" : "Pune", 
    "locations" : [ 
        "Bhawani Peth", 
        "Bibvewadi", 
    ]
}
```

Note that the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) can be modified to whatever you need or be case insensitive, but the most efficient form will be the "start with" in an exact case as is shown. So use that where possible.

This would require you to access the raw "pymongo" driver underlying MongoEngine in order to get that basic "collection" object and use the aggregate method. I'm not completely sure on the correct method to do this as sources vary, but this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoengine-users/O3lYpDvdnS4) may be of some help to doing that part.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, while this works as expected in the mongoshell I was wondering if there is a way to run it from django? My setup uses django with mongoengine. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @KumarDeepam There is a link at the bottom of the answer to a discussion about accessing the pymongo driver from the MongoEngine configuration. Failing that you can always directly create a pymongo instance in code. At any rate, this sort of query is out of the scope of django style queries and need to be done in the raw pymongo style, which is practically identical to the shell syntax as shown.